# Generating JSON with cursor in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database-cursor

What is the best way to extract results from a cursor to a JSON format using version 5.7?

I need the JSON to look something like this:

```
{
  "2018V": {
    "students": {
      "1": {
        "fName": "John",
        "dob": "4/8/1998",
        "classes": []
      },... and more student ID's
    }
  },... and more semesters
}
```

I was advised to use only one cursor to fetch a lot of data instead of three or four nested ones, so the cursor looks like this:

```
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE infoJson JSON DEFAULT '{}';
DECLARE currSemester CHAR(10);
DECLARE currStudentID INT;
DECLARE currStudentName VARCHAR(140);
DECLARE currStudentSSN VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE currCourseNumber CHAR(10);
DECLARE curStudentsInfo CURSOR FOR SELECT `StudentCourses`.semester, `Students`.studentID, `Students`.studentName,`Students`.studentSSN, `StudentCourses`.courseNumber
FROM `StudentCourses`
INNER JOIN `Students` ON `StudentCourses`.studentID = `Students`.studentID
ORDER BY `StudentCourses`.semester;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

OPEN curStudentsInfo;
infoLoop: LOOP
  FETCH curStudentsInfo INTO currSemester, currStudentID, currStudentName, currStudentSSN, currCourseNumber;
  IF done THEN
    CLOSE curStudentsInfo;
    LEAVE infoLoop;
  END IF;
  -- Code here
END LOOP infoLoop;
```

The data that I'm working with looks something like this:
Here are four people in total and only two semesters on record but there's a lot more in the database.

```
semester    studentID   studentName studentSSN  courseNumber
--------------------------------------------------------
2018H       3           Birkir Geir 2001979230  GSF2A3U
2018H       3           Birkir Geir 2001979230  STÆ303
2018V       5           Reynir      1508984089  STÆ203
2018V       6           Róbert Ingi 1707001234  STÆ603
...
```

Now what kind of approach should I take here? I've been trying to figure this out now for quite some time and I just find it so hard to code this kind of thing in MySQL. I don't know exactly what to use. I feel like everything I come up with would be a complete mess.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here?  Is there any chance you could handle this from your app layer, e.g. PHP?

Comment: The goal of. this assignment is to use a cursor. No PHP or anything.